# Intercepting a click in a UIWebView on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I need to intercept a click on a UIWebView on a video pre-roll advertisement and have this displayed in a new popup window instead of in the UIWebView which is quite small on the screen.

The issue is that I don't know what the URLs that are being clicked and also that these clicks are processed via Javascript on the page as well. There would also be Javascript reporting/tracking calls going out from the UIWebView in the background.

Is there anyway to detect that the UIWebView is opening a new page and instead of displaying that in place it get's displayed in a popup?

Comment: Implement `- webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` and inspect the `navigationType` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Great question. All you will have to do is implement the [UIWebViewDelegate protocols](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a).

This method:

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType

is likely the one you will use to detect all events happening within the UIWebView.

Comment: Not sure that this will work as the player that is running inside the Webview has multiple things that can happen in relation to the clicks e.g. depending on where the click is it could also pause the video as well as open the add. Looking at the available UIWebViewNavigationType https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIWebViewNavigationType I am also not sure I would get a UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked in the case of Javascript being run.